# Python: Is there a way I can run mainloop() in the background?

Tags: python, tkinter, program-entry-point

Is there a way I can run mainloop() in the background? I don't want to add the complexity of threads. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you have an application with only one thread there is no  foreground/background distinction :)

Comment: can you elaborate on what problem you think putting the event loop "in the background" will solve? For someone who is just now learning Tkinter (judging by your other question) you would do well to learn how the normal system works before trying to work around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The main loop of a GUI framework must *always* run in the foreground.

Comment: I know, I reversed the order, my program runs in the back and my gui in the front.

Comment: @TheDoctor: I have no clue what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this. The message loop runs in its thread and processes your message queue.

There isn't really any official distinction between background and foreground threads.  The thread that processes your message is typically called the foreground but it's not really any different from any other thread.  It's only convention that leads us to refer to threads foreground or background.

Ultimately, that main thread with the message loop in has the message loop at the top of its call stack and that's just the way it has to be.

It is possible to start a long running task and get it to frequently process messages, but this way requires a keen understanding of re-entrancy issues and often leads to insanity.

If you want long running background tasks then you probably need threads.

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping your message loop in the foreground, and your other processing in the background (say, with an [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method)? Especially if you don't want to use threads. However, I think threads or processes will probably work better in the long run.

Comment: `after` doesn't run something in the background, it merely puts it on the event loop to be run by the main thread after it has processed any other pending events. But you are correct that `after` is a good way to break up a large, time consuming task into smaller chunks.

Comment: @Bryan: you're right, I should have explained my statement better.