# Extend Vim GUI using Python tkinter

Tags: python, vim, plugins, tkinter, extend

I know there are a few ways to integrate gVIM in GTK using gtk.Socket and DBUS:

- [Pida](https://code.google.com/p/pida/)
- [gtkvim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=160)
- [anjuta-gvim](https://github.com/arunchaganty/vimjuta/)
- [VEE](http://wiki.kldp.org/wiki.php/VEE/english_page)
- [VimMate](http://vimmate.rubyforge.org/)
- [Vizinho](http://code.google.com/p/vizinho/)

But I was wondering if it is possible to say have a python plugin that uses tkinter to add extra GUI components to the gVIM GUI?

The problem is how to have two mainloops explained here:

[Python: Is there a way I can run mainloop() in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420885/python-is-there-a-way-i-can-run-mainloop-in-the-background)

My first try was (tkinter.vim):

```py
python << endpython

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()

endpython
```

Or even this (tkinter-thread.vim):

```py
python << endpython

import Tkinter
import threading
class MyTkApp(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def callback(self):
       self.root.quit()
    def run(self):
        self.root=Tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
        self.s = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.s.set('Foo')
        l = Tkinter.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.s)
        l.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
app = MyTkApp()
print 'now can continue running code while mainloop runs'

endpython
```

They both hang the gVIM GUI once you try to type something.

Is there any other way to extend gVIM GUI with other GUI components (windows/toolbar, ...)?

Comment: What kind of GUI components do you want to add to GVIM, and what for?

Comment: Let's say you want to add a new toolbar and extent gVIM to make it an IDE.  Use gVIM power and extend it for specific language and environment.  True that you can add menus and buttons, and add plugins for doing various things, but that's not what I want.